# Custom Dynamic Segment (NOT ID) - EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I want to have a dynamic segment path in Ember without using the `:id` attribute

As per the Ember Guides, I'm using the `serialize` method to achieve this.

Heres my Router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("orders", function(){
        this.resource('order', { path: ':order_sequence'}, function(){
            this.route('edit');
        })
    });
});
```

And my Route:

```
var OrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('order', params.order_sequence)
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return { order_sequence: model.get('sequence') };
  }
});

module.exports = OrderRoute;
```

However, my URL's still behave using the `id` attribute in the path instead of the `sequence` attribute..

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that your `OrderRoute`, isn't being used. So by default ember is generating a route with the default behavior of use the id, instead of :order_sequence. You can double check this putting an alert or console.log in your serialize method. Can you confirm it to me? In addition are you using ember-tools? What's the file name and location, of order route?

Comment: So I added an alert in my serialize method and it actually does fire on page load.

Yes, I am using ember-tools. the path to my order_route file is: /js/routes/order_route.js

Comment: By the way, im using FIXTURES as my sample data, not sure if that has anything to do with it..

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure we didn't understand your question correctly.  If my answer is correct below we should update your question to more properly show what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your browser caching something, because that's correct.  Are you passing in the id instead of the sequence/model in any of your transitionTo/transitionToRoute/link-to?

Oh, you aren't talking about the slug in the url, nor the route, you are talking about the id of your model.  You need to create a serializer for that particular model and override the primary key

```
App.OrderSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'sequence'
});
```

The Fixture Adapter has a constraint on defining the id, but you can lazily get around it by extending the fixture adapter and overriding a single method

```
App.OrderAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({

 fixturesForType: function(type) {
  if (type.FIXTURES) {
   var fixtures = Ember.A(type.FIXTURES);
   return fixtures.map(function(fixture){

    // aka we massasge the data a bit here so the fixture adapter won't whine so much
    fixture.id = fixture.sequence;
    var fixtureIdType = typeof fixture.id;
    if(fixtureIdType !== "number" && fixtureIdType !== "string"){
      throw new Error(fmt('the id property must be defined as a number or string for fixture %@', [fixture]));
    }
    fixture.id = fixture.id + '';
    return fixture;
   });
  }
  return null;
 },
});
```

Comment: Nope, cleared cache and checked from a different browser.

And, im testing by visiting the URL directly, not from any link-to or transitionTo hooks.

Comment: If you are visiting the url directly, how is it manifesting that it's using the id instead of the sequence?

Comment: Because when i visit /#/orders/5 directly, it loads the object with id: 5 -- i don't even have a sequence: 5.. Technically if i visit that url, it shouldn't work.. im basing my test on that

Comment: The slug and the serializer of the url have nothing to do with Ember Data.  It's important to remember that ED and Ember are two different products solving different things.

Comment: I guess the approach of making "`sequence`" the primary key makes sense. But, i've deleted the "id" property from my FIXTURES and added your `App.OrderSerialzer` approach and still get an error: `Uncaught Error: the id property must be defined as a number or string for fixture {sequence: 1, orders:` ....

Comment: Sorry, the fixture adapter has a constraint on 'id' being there, they figure it's fixture data, so you have complete control over it :)  That aside, you can still trick it with the code above.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Once I replace the fixture adapter with REST, I guess that's when I use the `RESTSerializer.extend` you mentioned first right?

Comment: That's correct, I might have to go submit some code to add that feature into the fixture adapter as well...